# Sharing Image on instagram in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, instagram

I am having an app in which I am sharing an image on instagram and it works perfectly fine.

As shown in the screenshot. When I press the button share on instagram it opens up in UIActivityviewcontroller.

Is it possible that If I click on Share on Instagram and and it takes me directly to the native instagram app?

If the user has other apps installed in his device that apps also shows because of the UIActivityViewController.

I don't want to show UIActivityviewcontroller saying "Open In Instagram".

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Edited**

I am taking a screenshot of a view and sharing that screenshot on Instagram.

When I click on a button share it opens up as shown in the screenshot which I don't want.

I am using the below code.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"];

                if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
                {
                    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
                    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                    imagename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ff.ig"];
                    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagename];
                    ////NSLog(@"%@",fullPathToFile);

                    igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", fullPathToFile]];

                    self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
                    self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
                    self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];


                        self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Image" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

     [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView:self.view animated: YES ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.documentInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:imgurl usingDelegate:self];

self.documentInteractionController=[UIDocumentInteractionController  interactionControllerWithURL:imgurl];

self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
```

Use this code in same sequence . Here documentInteractionController is object of UIDocumentInteractionController.just for your knowledge. you will get instagram only in "open in" window.

Save your image with igo extension instead of ig.

By this you will only get instagram option in your "Open in" Menu.

Or if you want to open directly instagram when you press the button you can pass the direct url of the app and it will lead you to the native instagram app.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you for reply but my image share sucessfully but i want to share image  without "open in instagram "is possible ?
when images share sucessfully then how to redirect to my app ?

Comment: Yes, you can directly go to the native instagram app by using **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]** line in the above code in if statement. Then you will be redirected to the native app. You can not be redirected to your app once you go to the native instagram app. You have to open your app again.

Comment: ok but what is instagramURL ? i tried NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"]; but no open native instagram app

Comment: Just see my above code. You can see that. Just add the line *[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]* after if and it will directly open the instagram app.

Answer (score 3):

for **swift**

```
 var instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")!
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
            var documentDirectory = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents")
            var saveImagePath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image.igo")
            var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.bestScoreShareView.takeSnapshot(W: 640, H: 640))
            imageData.writeToFile(saveImagePath, atomically: true)
            var imageURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(saveImagePath)!
           docController  = UIDocumentInteractionController()
            docController.delegate = self
            docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
            docController.URL = imageURL
            docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)

        } else {
            println("instagram not found")
        }
```

> **extension for take shapshot from uiview**

```
extension UIView {
    func takeSnapshot(#W: CGFloat, H: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        var cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        image.imageWithNewSize(CGSizeMake(W, H))
        return image
    }
}
```

> **extension for set image size**

```
extension UIImage {
     func imageWithNewSize(newSize:CGSize) ->UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        self.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Comment: impressive extensions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the size of your image.As it supports image bigger than 612*612 do check the size of your image you are posting