# How to share image to instagram within app in iOS?

Tags: ios, instagram

I have seen many questions related to my question and also got answer that there is no public api to share image to instagram within app. but my problem is that if i am opening instagram app from my app then there is no way to return back to my app and i also want to get username of logged in user before sharing image to instagram but can't get because as per my knowledge can't transfer data from one aap to another.

Comment: Did you see this? http://instagram.com/developer/authentication

Comment: Download Instagram sample code from here: https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk   and check this link http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ and for api console check http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: @Desdenova yes, i have seen this link and i can find username using this api but can't post image and if i try to post image by opening instagram app then it requires separate login

Comment: @iOSDeveloper please see my above comment

Comment: There is some example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954810/sharing-image-on-instagram-in-ios