# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, nsurl

I am trying to implement posting an image to Instagram in my iOS app. I have used the code in this post.

[Post UIImage to Instagram using Swift similar to SLComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406515/post-uiimage-to-instagram-using-swift-similar-to-slcomposeviewcontroller)

I need to change the line:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageInstagram, 1.0)!.writeToFile(jpgPath, atomically: true)
```

to:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageInstagram, 1.0)!.write(jpgPath, options: true)
```

for Swift 3 but then I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: you are passing String instead of URL.

Comment: what is jpgPath

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `string` as argument to write function which is invalid argument as write function takes `URL` as an argument.

So simply replace

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageInstagram, 1.0)!.write(jpgPath, options: true)
```

with this:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageInstagram, 1.0)!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: jpgPath), options: .atomic)
```

For more details have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410595-write)

Comment: Did you mean https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410595-write ? (Your link describes the `write(toFile:options:)` func)

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzytuła Thank you for pointing it. I have replaced the link.

Comment: Anyway, the one you linked to is still useful (you wouldn't have to initialize URL with string, just pass the string as parameter)

Comment: @VishalSonawane When I follow your suggestion I get the error "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled". I have combined your suggestion with Wolverine's below and it has got me passed the error. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageInstagram, 1.0)
```

> As I consider "jpgPath" is PATH where you are trying to save image.

if not then here is a example how you should create that PATH URL

```
let jpgPath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("instagram.jpg")

do {
    try jpegData.write(to: jpgPath, options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If **jpgPath** is a **String** (Which is in your case), you can try like this.

```
do {
    try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: jpgPath), options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```